# log4net reconnectonerror - is connect timeout necessary?

Tags: log4net-appender

We have a number of .NET applications that make use of log4net for logging to a sql server databsae. For various reasons (unrelated to log4net...I think) on occasion logging stops. The application might continue working but logging will not continue until the IIS application pool is recycled. The obvious solution would be to add reconnectonerror to the log4net appender. However, as I understand it it is always suggested that "connect timeout=1" be added to the appended connection string. Why?

What I mean is...

If log4net logging worked without "connect timeout=1" why would including  make adding "connect timeout=1" matter?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the act of reconnecting may block the calling thread.

More specifically, if a connection is not available, Log4Net will attempt to reconnect once there are enough messages for a batch.  If there is a chronic problem with the database, this could result in performance degradation -- especially if you have configured lots of logging or a small batch size.

One of Apache's design goals is to allow log statements to remain in production code without incurring high performance cost.  That's where the connect timeout suggestion comes from.  If you have to pay the cost of reconnecting, at least make it quick so you don't take too much of a performance hit.

Sources : 
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ReconnectOnError.html

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200506.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C7692DA@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E